# Create a table with data validation based on 2 or more columns

Tags: sql-server

I have been trying to create a production ERP using C# and SQL Server.

I want to create a table where the insert statement should only occur when at least one of the 3 main columns have a different value.

The main columns are `prod_date`, `order_no`, `mach_no`, `shift_no`, `prod_type`. If all the values are repeated a second time the data must not be entered.

```
create table p1_order(id int not null,
                      order_no int not null,
                      prod_date date notnull,
                      prod_type nvarchar(5),
                      shift_no int not null,
                      mach_no nvarchar(5) not null,
                      prod_qty,
                      float not null)
```

Comment: That DDL isn't valid. `prod_qty` lacks a data type, and your `float` lacks a column name (is `float` also the correct data choice? It rarely is). You also have `notnull` in one place, rather than `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this is by creating a unique constraint on the table.

```
alter table p1_order
add constraint UC_Order unique (prod_date,order_no,mach_no,shift_no,prod_type);
```

Due to some reason, if you are not able to create a unique constraint, you can write your query like the following using `NOT EXISTS`

```
insert into p1_order (order_no , prod_date , prod_type <remaining columns>) 
select 123, '2022-09-20 15:11:43.680', 't1' <remaining values>
where not exists 
    (select 1
     from p1_order 
     where order_no = 123 AND prod_date = '2022-09-20 15:11:43.680' <additional condition>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, You should check for the identical values when executing insert query, while writing your code. for example you can write:

```
if(prod_date == order_no == mach_no)// or any other 3 variables
{
 //error of identical values
}
else{
// your insert query
}
```